# Adding a Single Column in a DataBase using Hibernate AutoDDL?

Tags: java, hibernate

> I have 1 DATABASE having 10 schemas and in that I have one table name which is common in each schema.

I have to add a Single Column in my SQL Database using AutoDDL.But the problem is I am defining 10 HibernateCfg Files and I am defining single mapping file having configuration of 10 schemas.

> Can anyone guide me how can I make the Code generic and fast?
>   My Generic I mean that can I define more than 1 hibernate Cfg file for a Single DataBase.

Is this standard way of doing things?

I have done Configuration like this:

[hibernate.cfg.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxENn.png)

[Subscription.hbm.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAfoQ.png)